# When adding links in comments, can http:// be automatically added if no other protocol is specified?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

I'm using FireFox and it never displays the `http://` prefix. I had copied and pasted the URL of a webpage, I was going to link to in a comment, and was confused when it didn't work. It turns out when adding a link to the comments the link needs to begin with http://. Can this be automatically added if no protocol is specified?

For example one must enter in a comment

`Try searching [here](http://www.example.com).`

instead of

`Try searching [here](example.com).`

Alternatively a message could be displayed reminding that no protocol was given.  Yes, assuming `http://` would break `https://` but if the user didn't specify `https://` it would be broken anyways (so this concern doesn't really make sense to me?). The problem is it's not apparent why a link isn't working since `http://` isn't usually required. This would also help when people manually type things in, for example `yahoo.com` instead of `http://yahoo.com`

I'm still wondering why people think this is a bad idea?

Comment: My Firefox (just a single upper case F by the way) and other browsers on my Mac also don't *display* the `http://` part, but when copying a URL I surely still get it, also in Firefox. If your Firefox does not include it when copying, then I'm sure that's unintended, and hence is a bug that needs to be reported to Mozilla.

Comment: Testing: **(1)** `[this](/q/7931)` yields [this](/q/7931)  **(2)** `[this](www.example.com)` yields [this](www.example.com) **(3)** `[this](http://www.example.com)` yields [this](http://www.example.com) **(4)** `www.example.com` (so: without any `[...](...)` Markdown) yields www.example.com **(5)** `http://www.example.com.` (so: even with a trailing dot) yields http://www.example.com. (And [a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dQjxM.png), and compare to handling [in a regular post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hFh9Y.png).)

Comment: [click here](www.example.com) vs [click here](http://www.example.com) <= this one had http://

Answer (score -2):

This would break if I wanted to include an https:// rather than an http:// (or in fact any other supported protocol (not sure if there are any others)

It really isn't hard to add 7 characters.

Comment: Not sure I follow your thinking, you do realize I'm suggesting not to add anything if any protocol is there? So it wouldn't dumbly always append http to avoid situations  like http:// https:// example.com

Comment: Sure - I just don't see it as a good thing. I would always want to specify the protocol. I'm only one person though - if others like the idea, you'll get upvotes.

Comment: @Rory: maybe not for the tech sites here, but it might be harder on other sites where users aren't that familiar with all those protocols.